Duplicate Key error while using GoRouter StatefulShellRoute with redirect
I'm using GoRouter for navigation in my Flutter app, but while using the redirect function with StatefulShellRoute, I get a Duplicate Globalkey error. I've attached the minimal reproduction code (The attached Code is dartpad compatible).
Steps to reproduce

Copy and run the code on https://dartpad.dev
Press Login Button
Goto Profile Tab
Press logout button

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class LoggedinNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  LoggedinNotifier() : super(false);

  Future<void> set(bool val) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    state = val;
  }
}

final loggedInProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<LoggedinNotifier, bool>((ref) => LoggedinNotifier());

class NavigationKeys {
  static final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final homeNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Home');
  static final profileNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Profile');
}

enum AppRoutes {
  home,
  profile,
  profileLoggedIn,
  profileLogin,
}

final appRouterProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final loggedIn = ref.watch(loggedInProvider);

  return GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: '/home',
    routes: [
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        branches: [
          StatefulShellBranch(routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/home',
              name: AppRoutes.home.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const Scaffold(
                body: Center(child: Text('Home')),
              ),
            )
          ], navigatorKey: NavigationKeys.homeNavigatorKey),
          StatefulShellBranch(routes: [
            GoRoute(
                path: '/profile',
                name: AppRoutes.profile.name,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Consumer(
                    builder: (context, ref, child) => TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await ref.read(loggedInProvider.notifier).set(false);
                        },
                        child: const Text('Logout')),
                  );
                },
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'authentication/login',
                    name: AppRoutes.profileLogin.name,
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return Consumer(
                        builder: (context, ref, child) => TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await ref
                                  .read(loggedInProvider.notifier)
                                  .set(true);
                            },
                            child: const Text('Login')),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ])
          ], navigatorKey: NavigationKeys.profileNavigatorKey),
        ],
        builder: (context, state, navigationShell) => Scaffold(
          body: navigationShell,
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              enableFeedback: true,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
              onTap: (value) {
                navigationShell.goBranch(
                  value,
                );
              },
              items: const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: 'Home'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline), label: 'Profile')
              ]),
        ),
      )
    ],
    navigatorKey: NavigationKeys.rootNavigatorKey,
    redirect: (context, state) {
      if (!loggedIn && !state.uri.toString().contains('/authentication')) {
        return state.namedLocation(AppRoutes.profileLogin.name);
      }
      return null;
    },
  );
});

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: ref.watch(appRouterProvider));
  }
}


This is the error
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [GlobalObjectKey int#b8c6a]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- _BranchNavigatorProxy-[StatefulShellBranch#a507a](state: _BranchNavigatorProxyState#1f5f1)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3317:15)
framework.dart:3317
#1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3342:8)
framework.dart:3342
#2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1169:19)
binding.dart:1169
#3      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:468:5)
binding.dart:468
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1397:15)
binding.dart:1397
#5      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1318:9)
binding.dart:1318
#6      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1176:5)
binding.dart:1176
#7      _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
hooks.dart:312
#8      PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:419:5)
platform_dispatcher.dart:419
#9      _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
hooks.dart:283
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════


Solution: Fixed it by declaring the navigation keys inside the router function.
final appRouterProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
 final loggedIn = ref.watch(loggedInProvider);

 final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
 final homeNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Home');
 final profileNavigatorKey =
     GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Profile');


 return GoRouter();
//Rest of the code
}

Another Solution is removing the static keyword from the NavigationKeys class and using the keys inside the GoRouter by creating an object, like this:
navigatorKey: NavigationKeys().profileNavigatorKey
